# Root loci transfer function

Tags: control-theory

Hi I asked a question earlier about this problem:

$$T(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)H(s)}$$

Where

$$H(s) = \frac{s}{s+1}$$ $$G(s) = \frac{k(s+4)}{(s+2)(s^2+s+6)}$$
.

Poles resulting: $$-1, -2, -0.5 + 2.4j, -0.5 - 2.4j$$

Zeros resulting: $$0, -4$$

centroid: $$= (-1 + -2 + -0.5 + 2.4j + -0.5 - 2.4j + 4) /2 = 0$$

I am now calculating the breakaway point using the characteristic equation.

$$1 + G(s)H(s) = 0$$

After simplification and taking the derivative with respect to s

$$ 2s^5 + 16s^4+32s^3+12s^2+6s + 24 = 0$$

A 5th order polynomial?

This question is pulled of an old final. No computers aloud. We were showed a trick using division but the highest we did in class was 4th order. I feel like I'm doing something wrong any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for transfer functions we can always write
$$H = \frac{P}{R}$$
where $P$ and $R$ are polynomials. You wrote
$$1 + GH = 1+\frac{Q}{L}\frac{P}{R} = 0,$$
or
$$LR + QP = 0.$$ 
For any two polynomials $P,R$, $\deg(PR) = \deg P + \deg R$ and $\deg (P + R) \leq  \max(\deg P,\deg R)$, with $<$ only following if they are the same order have have some number of leading coefficients opposite--which is not the case for any polynomial here. Thus
$$\deg(LR + QP) = \max(\deg L + \deg R, \deg Q + \deg P) = \max(1+3,1+1) = 4.$$
You must have made a mistake.